# Parsing single-quoted string with escaped quotes with Nom 5

Tags: rust, nom

I'm new to Rust and Nom and I'm trying to parse a (single) quoted string which may contain escaped quotes, e.g. `'foo\'  bar'` or `'λx → x'`, `''` or `'  '`.

I found the `escaped!` macro, whose [documentation](https://docs.rs/nom/5.0.1/nom/macro.escaped.html) says:

> The first argument matches the normal characters (it must not accept the control character), the second argument is the control character (like \ in most languages), the third argument matches the escaped characters

Since I want to match anything but a backslash in the matcher for “normal characters”, I tried using [`take_till!`](https://docs.rs/nom/5.0.1/nom/macro.take_till.html):

```rust
    named!(till_backslash<&str, &str>, take_till!(|ch| ch == '\\'));
    named!(esc<&str, &str>, escaped!(call!(till_backslash), '\\', one_of!("'n\\")));

    let (input, _) = nom::character::complete::char('\'')(input)?;
    let (input, value) = esc(input)?;
    let (input, _) = nom::character::complete::char('\'')(input)?;

    // … use `value`
```

However, when trying to parse `'x'`, this returns `Err(Incomplete(Size(1)))`. When searching for this, people generally recommend using `CompleteStr`, but that's not in Nom 5. What's the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: It seems, that you are (still) using nom4. There's a new version (5) which kind of obsoletes the macros, e.g. `names!` and uses functions instead. You can take a look at https://docs.rs/nom/5.0.1/nom/

Comment: @hellow: Maybe's that's where the disconnect is? I could very well be misunderstanding something… I *am* actually using Nom 5.0.1, but I'm still using many of the macros because if I go to https://docs.rs/nom/5.0.1/nom/character/complete/index.html, there are very few combinators, and nothing like `escaped` or `take_till`. For bytes there *is* an `escaped` function (https://docs.rs/nom/5.0.1/nom/bytes/complete/fn.escaped.html), but I'm not working on bytes, I'm working on (unicode) text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When operating in the so-called streaming mode, `nom` may returns `Incomplete` to indicate that it can't decide and needs more data. The `nom` 4 introduced `CompleteStr`. Alongside with `CompleteByteSlice`, they were complete input counterpart of `&str` and `&[u8]`. The parsers taken them as input work in complete mode.

They are gone in `nom` 5. In `nom` 5, macro based parsers always work in streaming mode as you've observed. For parser combinators that would work differently in streaming and complete mode, there are different versions of them in separate sub-modules, such as `nom::bytes::streaming` and `nom::bytes::complete`.

For all these gory details you may want to check out [this blog post](http://unhandledexpression.com/general/2019/06/17/nom-5-is-here.html), especially the section *Streaming VS complete parsers*.

Also, the function combinators are preferred over the macro ones in `nom` 5. Here is one way to do it:

```rust
//# nom = "5.0.1"
use nom::{
    branch::alt,
    bytes::complete::{escaped, tag},
    character::complete::none_of,
    sequence::delimited,
    IResult,
};

fn main() {
    let (_, res) = parse_quoted(r#"'foo\'  bar'"#).unwrap();
    assert_eq!(res, r#"foo\'  bar"#);
    let (_, res) = parse_quoted("'λx → x'").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(res, "λx → x");
    let (_, res) = parse_quoted("'  '").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(res, "  ");
    let (_, res) = parse_quoted("''").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(res, "");
}

fn parse_quoted(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, &str> {
    let esc = escaped(none_of("\\\'"), '\\', tag("'"));
    let esc_or_empty = alt((esc, tag("")));
    let res = delimited(tag("'"), esc_or_empty, tag("'"))(input)?;

    Ok(res)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was under the (false) impression that the functions from `nom::bytes` woudn't work for `&str`, but it seems that it even works if I change the delimiters from single quotes to e.g. !